# fopen fails in special condition (windows+eclipse cdt+mingw)

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb, mingw, mingw32

I'd like to develop a simple windows application with MingW + Eclipse on Windows.

But I can't debug program with GDB because if I run the program in debug mode, fopen always fails (returns NULL pointer).

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
```

Does anyone know how to avoid such a phenomena?

case 1) ran program normally (not debug mode)

works fine.

case 2) ran program using gdb (not using eclipse CDT)

works fine.

case 3) ran program using eclipse CDT and gdb

doesn't work. (fopen always returns NULL pointer)

---

gcc 4.6.2
gdb 7.6.1
eclipse 4.6.1 (neon)
Windows7 Enterprise (SP1) 64bit edition

---

Thanks for many useful advices!
At first I don't know perror function,,
Here is my test codes.

```
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    char lineBuffer[256];
    if (fp) {
        while (fgets(lineBuffer, 256, fp) != NULL) {
            doSomething(lineBuffer);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else {
        perror("error ");
    }
```

filename are passed by argv/argc.

Firstly I used relative path and perror result is following (someone.txt)

```
error : No such file or directory
```

Secondery I used absolute path and perror result is following.(D:\someone.txt)

```
error : Invalid argument
```

Comment: Where is the file on disk?  Which file name do you specify?  Which directory is the program run?  Does it change when you debug?

Comment: What error message do you get when you call `perror` after getting the NULL pointer?  You *are* performing error checking, right?

Comment: Try using full path not relative and see if it works.

Comment: I would really hope that your code, which you failed to post, is actually checking the returned value from an call to a system function, including `fopen()` and when an error is indicated, calling the function: `perror()` to output your error message text AND the error message from the call.  Similar to: `perror( "fopen for .... Failed" );`

Comment: Thanks for many advices. I will update my original post.

Comment: Solved.

In second case, argv is escaped by single quotation like a 'someone.txt'.

If I set filename directly, fopen ends with success.

Thanks for your many advices!

Comment: Tip: make error messages informative and add printable sentinels to bracket strings.  `else {
        perror("error "); fprintf(stderr, "fopen( \"%s\")\n",  filename);
    }`